# Captive portal detection by Apple Oses, iOS 'splash CNA popup' does not show?

Tags: networking, wifi, captive-portal

I built a captive portal (Linux Debian router),
providing a WifiHotspot based on `hostapd` and iptables rules ( like this: http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal ).

It works, by redirecting any request to a local welcome login page.

On Android, Kindle: the portal is detected as captive. And something happens ( notification, alert, popup...)

On iOS, the CNA (**Captive Network Assistant**), nothing happens. Unless I put `wispr` payload in the local pages ('Reply' one, MessageType=100, code=0). 
Example: http://www.coova.org/node/4346

My question is: why ? Why without WispR "tag" there is no CNA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the wispr payload, it is required.

I must confess I have been painful and unsuccessfuk in finding doc about. A bounty is to come about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650338/apple-documentation-about-wispr-cna

Comment: This needs more detail, e.g. Apple dev documents describing this.

Comment: @Sven There is no dev documents for this (it does not concern iOS or  OSX apps development). The question is about wispr, answer is 'yes, needed'.